# Electrum on Android - where is wallet.dat hidden?

Tags: electrum, wallet-recovery, wallet.dat, bitcoin-wallet-app, android

Does anyone knows where Electrum android app saves its wallet.dat on phone/sd memory?

If such files exists is it possible to transfer it between phones?

I have forgotten my seed words (and do not want to move btcs from wallet to another) and wonder if this is an option to transfer this file like on desktop (with wallet.dat file)

Comment: electrum standard wallet file name is default_wallet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electrum doesnt use `wallet.dat` file, those are used by Bitcoin Core. Electrum creates wallet files in `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Electrum\\wallets` for Windows, `/home/user/.electrum/wallets/` for Linux and `/data/data/org.electrum.electrum/files/data/wallets` for Android. If forgot seed words, move BTC to another wallet and keep backup info safe if you can.